# Azure Function ScaledJob in AKS should complete after complete

Tags: node.js, azure, kubernetes, azure-functions, keda

I have an Azure Function in NodeJS running in an AKS cluster. Now it will be deployed based on queue storage messages. After the function/job is done processing it should turn to complete and be removed. For some reason it doesn't.

Below is the KEDA job I've deployed to AKS:

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
metadata:
  name: keda-queue-storage-job
  namespace: orchestrator
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    completionMode: Indexed
    parallelism: 10
    completions: 1
    backoffLimit: 3
    template:
      metadata:
        namespace: orchestrator
        labels:
          app: orchestrator
      spec:
        affinity:
          podAntiAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              - labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - orchestrator
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        containers:
          - name: orchestrator
            image: {acr}:latest
            env:
              - name: AzureFunctionsJobHost__functions__0
                value: orchestrator
            envFrom:
              - secretRef:
                  name: orchestrator
            readinessProbe:
              failureThreshold: 3
              periodSeconds: 10
              successThreshold: 1
              timeoutSeconds: 240
              httpGet:
                path: /
                port: 80
                scheme: HTTP
            startupProbe:
              failureThreshold: 3
              periodSeconds: 10
              successThreshold: 1
              timeoutSeconds: 240
              httpGet:
                path: /
                port: 80
                scheme: HTTP
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: 4
                memory: 10G
        restartPolicy: Never
  pollingInterval: 10 # Optional. Default: 30 seconds
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1 # Optional. Default: 100. How many completed jobs should be kept.
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1 # Optional. Default: 100. How many failed jobs should be kept.

  triggers:
    - type: azure-queue
      metadata:
        queueName: searches
        queueLength: "1"
        activationQueueLength: "0"
        connectionFromEnv: AzureWebJobsStorage
        accountName:{account-name}
```

It seems like the Azure Function isn't signalling to kubernetes that it's done. When I run a process.exit(0) then the entire process stops too early it seems since any outputBindings aren't being done.

Does anyone know how to make the job complete?

Comment: When you exit the process using process.exit(0), it immediately terminates the process, which might not allow the outputBindings to be executed. To ensure that the outputBindings are executed before the process is terminated `context.done();
`